# In Multi Image Selector OnActivityResult() method is not getting called in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, onactivityresult, android-image-capture

I am trying to make image selector for application.For that i am using multi-image-selector library which is perfeclty works when used in activity ,but here i want to use it in fragment.so in fragment OnActivityResult() method is not getting called.Can anyone help me to solve this?

Here's my code:
**MainActivity.java:(My Main Activity)**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new Image_Selecter()).commit();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //  Utilz.printLog("Parentactivity", "onActivityResult");
        Log.e("hererererer", "hererererer");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) { 

          new Image().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

**Image:(My Fragment)**

```
public class Image extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<String> mSelectPath;
    private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE = 2;
    ArrayList<Uri> mMedia = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    Uri uri;
    ImageView img;
    protected static final int REQUEST_STORAGE_READ_ACCESS_PERMISSION = 101;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_image, container, false);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pickImage();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
    public void pickImage() {
            MultiImageSelector selector = new MultiImageSelector(getActivity());
            selector.showCamera(true);
            selector.multi();
            selector.count(1);
            selector.origin(mSelectPath);
            selector.start(getActivity(), REQUEST_IMAGE);
        }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) {
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                mSelectPath = data.getStringArrayListExtra(MultiImageSelector.EXTRA_RESULT);
                mMedia.clear();
                for (String p : mSelectPath) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(p);
                    mMedia.add(uri);
                }
                uri = mMedia.get(0);
                Log.e("uri", "  " + uri);
                if (!uri.toString().contains("content://")) {
                    uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(uri.toString()));
                    Log.e("in if", " uri = " + uri);
                }
                try {
                    Glide.with(this)
                            .load(uri)
                            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .into(img);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Exceptionn", " " + e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("Parentactivity", "onActivityResult");

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) { //use request code as REQUEST_IMAGE while starting intent for camera

        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame);
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);//calling fragments onActivityResult here
    }
}
```

Comment: but there is an option to get the result on the fragment, no need to go back to the activity

Comment: why not use the startActivityForResult from the fragment instead?

Comment: we have to use startActivityForResult from the fragment  then we can get result in onActivityResult()

Comment: @chirag your RequestCode isn't 11 or 111 that @gaurang has, it is 2 `REQUEST_IMAGE  = 2`

Comment: can you post your error log? where your are getting null pointer exception

Comment: the code of @gaurang assumes that you have a fragment container `fragment_container`, so if you ( @Chirag) go with that code you have to change it to work on your scenario.

Comment: @gmetax- I have used frame layout in main activity and inflated layout from fragment.

Comment: fragment_container frame layout  which is containing my fragment, it not necessary that questioner and my container are same.

Comment: because I believe that @Chirag is new on android I wanted to point out that also maybe he didn't check that

Comment: @gmetax-Yeah i am absolute beginner in android.I have added my main activity code above check if u find something wrong .thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC `onActivityResult` doesn't get called on a Fragment, it gets called on your parent Activity. You would need to catch this in the Activity and forward the result on to the fragment.

Comment: you are wrong... the OnActivityResult can get called on Fragment! https://stackoverflow.com/a/6147919/2401265

Comment: Fair enough https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment

Answer (score 0):

you have to call it with intent

```
public void pickImage() {
       Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MultiImageSelectorActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra(MultiImageSelectorActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_CAMERA, true);
       intent.putExtra(MultiImageSelectorActivity.EXTRA_SELECT_COUNT, 1);
       intent.putExtra(MultiImageSelectorActivity.EXTRA_SELECT_MODE, MultiImageSelectorActivity.MODE_MULTI);
       intent.putStringArrayListExtra(MultiImageSelectorActivity.EXTRA_DEFAULT_SELECTED_LIST, mSelectPath);
       startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
}
```

if you were doing `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);`
the on `OnActivityResult()` will happen on activity instead of fragment. The way you are using it is like that, so you need to use the intent way.

also that maybe will make your code to work

```
public void pickImage() {
        MultiImageSelector selector = new MultiImageSelector(getContext());
        selector.showCamera(true);
        selector.multi();
        selector.count(1);
        selector.origin(mSelectPath);
        selector.start(getContext(), REQUEST_IMAGE);
}
```

Comment: @gmetax- in the intent way it shows the null pointer errors onimageselected,selectImageFromGrid such methods of library class.

Comment: @Chirag where are those?

Comment: can't understand you, try the way with `getContext` instead of `getActivity`

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods which looks same but behaves little bit different.
If method is called by from activity, its not going to give callback to fragment unless called from fragment.

```
Activity.startActivityForResult()
Fragment.startActivityForResult()
```

Check out the library if there is way to calling it from fragment.

I dont know the library, just imaging if you can pass fragment to 
`MultiImageSelector selector = new MultiImageSelector(getActivity());` or `selector.start(getActivity(), REQUEST_IMAGE);`

Good luck

Emre